# Show languages when using marker

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript, templavoila

My setup in template of Typo3 looks like this:

```
temp.langMenu = HMENU
temp.langMenu {
    special = language
    special {
        value = 0,1,2
    }
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul class="languageSwitch">|</ul>
        NO {
            allWrap = <li class="de">|</li>|*|<li class="en">|</li>|*|<li class="fr">|</li>
            stdWrap.override = DE || EN || FR
        }
        ACT = 1
        ACT < .NO
        ACT {
            allWrap = <li class="de active">|</li>|*|<li class="en active>|</li>|*|<li class="fr active">|</li>
        }

        USERDEF1 = 1
        USERDEF1 < .NO
        USERDEF1 {
            noLink = 1
            doNotShowLink = 1
        }
    }
}

page {
    10 {
        marks {
            langMenu < temp.langMenu
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to show the languages. I have tried using markers but in frontend it is only showing me: **###langMenu###**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show us the template

Comment: is there you miss "page = PAGE" before you assign markers?